# nginx: what is the equivalent to a2enmod?

Tags: nginx

I am switching from Apache2 to nginx.

What is the equivalent of these commands in nginx world?

```
sudo a2enmod ssl
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo a2enmod headers 
sudo a2enmod expires 
sudo a2enmod php5
```

many thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no equivalent, as [Nginx modules are selected at compile time](http://wiki.nginx.org/Modules).  The referenced Nginx docs will show the standard modules.  Running `nginx -V` will show the compile options.  For example:

```
$ nginx -V
nginx version: nginx/0.7.61
built by gcc 4.2.4 (Ubuntu 4.2.4-1ubuntu4)
configure arguments: --prefix=/usr/local --sbin-path=/usr/local/sbin --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi --with-http_flv_module --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module
```

As a side note, a2enmod is a Debian/Ubuntu-ism; other Linux distros will enable Apache modules in different ways.

Comment: Now you could use `load_module` config directive if you are using any dynamic modules https://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#load_module

Comment: This answer is a bit outdated; as @PeterW writes, there is loadable module support in nginx nowadays. At least the `nginx-full` (and possibly `nginx-light` also?) packages for Debian/Ubuntu are compiled and packaged this way. There is a number of `libnginx-mod-*` packages available in addition to the modules compiled into the `/usr/sbin/nginx` binary.